# If your birthday isn’t in summer, when do you buy supplies, especially if you are muggle? Would your escort come back in summer?

Tags: harry-potter

I know that muggle-borns get escorts and such, and that their letters are delivered in person, but what happens if they have school on their birthday? Does the escort return on the weekend, or do they wait for summer or what?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21928/do-muggleborns-get-their-letter-on-their-11th-birthday-or-the-summer-before-they?rq=1

Comment: As the question linked above shows, you are starting from a wrong assumption, and your question therefore doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 14):

As [the answer to a related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21935/19561) indicates, the Hogwarts Acceptance Letter is **not** delivered on the students' birthday, but at the start of the summer before the students start at Hogwarts.

Note that Harry's letters started coming in *before* his eleventh birthday. Only because of Vernon Dursley's refusal to let Harry read his mail did it become necessary to deliver the letter in person on his birthday.

This means that if muggle-born students need an escort to Diagon Alley, one will be provided for them *then*, not on their birthday, but when they go shopping for school supplies.

Comment: So, the fact that it happened to be his birthday was (in-universe) presumably more coincidence than anything else (out-of-universe, it makes the whole thing more of a coming-of-age thing than it would be otherwise). I mean, I suppose Hagrid might have hurried (or delayed a day or two) if he knew he could deliver it on his birthday, but it wasn't a rule. That makes sense.